# Data splitting into training and testing data

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to split a data and I am getting this error

```
 > training <- subset(data, split == "TRUE")
Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 768 but subscript `r` has size 9.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

This was the code I tried

```
  split <- sample.split(data, SplitRatio = 0.7)
    split
    training <- subset(data, split == "TRUE")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the code was aiming to do - I'm assuming you're trying to split out a training dataset of 70% of the whole to work on? Since you've tagged 'tidyverse', I assume you're comfortable using tidyverse principles to achieve the same goal.

Consider the code below:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
        ID = c(1:1000)
        ,X = c(rnorm(1000, 0, 1))
) %>% mutate(
        y = X + c(rnorm(1000, 0, 0.05))
)

set.seed(100)

train <- sample_frac(dat, size = 0.7)
test <- dat %>% 
        anti_join(
                train, by = "ID"
        )
```

I've loaded the tidyverse library and then created a dataframe that houses all of my readings (with associated IDs). I've saved this dataframe as 'dat'. I also 'set.seed' to make sure my split is reproducible.

From there, you simply have to use the 'sample_frac' function to take a sample of the dataset, and then use the 'anti_join' function to collect the remaining elements as your test set.

Hopefully that helps?

EDIT: If you take that exact code snippet into R and run it, you may also need to install the tidyverse packages to make the code run:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

Once you've done that, you should be able to step through the code line by line to see what it's doing.

EDIT2: I've decided to amend your code to achieve the training set you were looking for:

```
# Delete these lines
split <- sample.split(data, SplitRatio = 0.7)
split

# This should produce a dataset called 'training'
training <- sample_frac(data, size = 0.7)
```